# Spring CrudRepository same erasure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have my own custom repository but when I try to override/use CrudRepository it gives me "both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other". Please see below.

```java
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

    //<S extends T> S save(S entity); //Parent method
    Person save(Person person);//It accepts this 

    //<S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);//Parent method
    Iterable<Person> saveAll(Iterable<Person> persons);//But does not accept this. why can I not use/override this?
    //This Gives error "both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java generics work through the concept known as erasure, meaning that under the hood all generics get transformed into `<Object>`. This unfortunately is one of the limitations of Java making sure it is backwards compatible with code written before Java 5 and generics.

Compiler sees both methods with identical names and identical parameters.
Just change the name of one of the methods from `saveAll` to `saveAllPeople` or whatever and it will work.

Comment: then how come this is fine  Person save(Person person); it has same name and params. as well

Comment: Person is not a Generic. Generics are surrounded by <>
                                                                                   
  For compiler these methods are same
  1. Iterable<Person> saveAll(Iterable<Person> persons);
  2. Iterable<Object> saveAll(Iterable<Object> persons);
  3. Iterable<Whatever> saveAll(Iterable<Whatever> persons);

Comment: Person is not generic? <S extends T> S save(S entity); here is base method. So the questions  Person save(Person person); works . But.  <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);  this does not work Iterable<Person> saveAll(Iterable<Person> persons);/